# CSS: Using two general selectors to select same element

Tags: html, css

How can I select the same element using general sibling. This I needed to try checkbox:checked technique to use it as a switch(some experimentation).

```css
input:checked:after{
//I wanted two psuedo class to work together
//but this selector isnt valid
  
  content:"text";
}

//so i tried below

input:checked ~ span ~ input:after{
  content:"text";

//but above isnt working either
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" checked><span></span>
```

Comment: Try `input:checked + span {}` to style the `<span>` when the checkbox is `checked`.

Comment: `::after` `::before`, two colons.

Answer (score 0):

Comment marks for CSS are like

```
/*  Comment */
```

In order to get your CSS to run, I had to delete those // marks, above.
I was able to get the code to work like this:

```
input[type='checkbox']:checked ~ span::after{
     content:'text';
}
```

with HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" checked><span></span>
```

My output was a checked checkbox with the word "text" after it.  Notice that I needed the pseudo-element double colon marks.  It's a little bit different from the pseudo-class colon mark used with "checked".

References:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements
https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/

Comment: Thanks regarding the comment part // 

The css behaviori tried to achieve is misunderstood here.

I wanted to try something given in this URL https://css-tricks.com/the-checkbox-hack/

Comment: That example has another part to it:  the relationship between an input and its label.  In that example, the checkbox is simply places far, far out of the viewport.  Yet, the label is associated with it.  When you go to the demo page, notice how there is another CSS declaration block for the label.  That's an important part.